# localStorage to save navbar state

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, local-storage

I want to use localStorage to store the sidebar toggle so browser can remember the last toggle. Can someone please take a look at this code and tell me why it's not working?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var sidebarshow = localStorage.getItem('sidebar') == 'true';
    $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active', sidebar);

    $("#toggle").click(function() {
         $("#sidebar").toggleClass("slow",function() {
             localStorage.setItem('sidebarshow', 'active');
         });
         $("#sidebar").toggleClass("active");
    }); 
});
```

CSS

```
#sidebar.active {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #1F6482;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
    color: #FFF;
}
#sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #1F6482;
    width: 75px;
    height: 100%;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

Comment: Look at your code and?

Comment: sorry im not really too familiar with this, i am trying to learn it. im trying to check localstorage of the staute of the sidebar so it can display it. then is the toggle is clicked to change sidebar width and alse save it in localstorage. Any help you offer will be appreciated.

Comment: What is `sidebar`? You are not setting the `localStorage` in your else condition. And please run this and tell us what exactly is not working and the expected result.

Comment: Sidebar is the name given to localstorage to store by. Also when i click on the toggle  button, it switches from normally state to active ( css width changes from width 75px to 250px) but it is not storing the state in localstorage. when i refresh the page it goes back to normal.

Comment: create fiddle and share link to your code

Comment: Why are you toggling a class named "slow"? You should read [the documentation for the `toggleClass` method](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem: 1) you did not set the localStorage for key 'sidebar', But accessing will result into unexpected values.

```
var sidebarshow = localStorage.getItem('sidebar') == 'true';
```

Problem: 2) you are setting the localStorage for key 'sidebarshow', But you are not used any where. (at least in above code)

```
localStorage.setItem('sidebarshow', 'active');
```

Think of localStorage as a just **object with key and values are of type string**. Make sure to set the value first and get them later.

Here is sample code working.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    /*
    if (window && window.localStorage.getItem('sidebar') === 'active') {
        // if it active show it as active
        $("#sidebar").addClass("active");
    } else {
        $("#sidebar").removeClass("active");
    } */
    
    $("#toggle").click(function() {
         $("#sidebar").toggleClass("active");
         var updated = '';
         if (window.localStorage.getItem('sidebar') === 'active') {
             updated = 'not_active';
         } else {
             updated = 'active';
         }
         window.localStorage.setItem('sidebar', updated);
    }); 
});
```

```css
#sidebar.active {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #1F6482;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
    color: #FFF;
}
#sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #1F6482;
    width: 75px;
    height: 100%;
    color: #FFF;
}

#toggle {
    margin-left: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sidebar"> Sidebar here </div>

<button id="toggle"> toggle </button>
```

Please check the screenshot of chrome debug console example with slightly changed to test.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the reply, but is it possible if you can please post an example of how this showed look? thanks.

Comment: @SoulTech, np! check the updated answer and sample code. Hope this helps.

Comment: Error:{
  "message": "Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': The document is sandboxed and lacks the 'allow-same-origin' flag.",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 40,
  "colno": 10
}




**Thats what i get when i run the code. i also tired it in my system and it is displaying as i want it to but its still returning back to normal. it did not store the state of the toggle clicked.**

Comment: @SoulTech, That error because of sandboxed environment. Please check my updated answer at end to test in chrome debug browser. I have slightly modified the function to work in console.

Comment: Thanks, i really appreciate your help. One last thing, how can i check when the page loads to check localStorage first, if it is active or not so it displays according to what was saved in localStorage.

Comment: @SoulTech, sure, I just updated the answer with sample code. I have commented here, But this should work in your application

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Admin-LTE v-3 package for front-end and wants to save the state of sidebar-collapse use this technique........ and an above solution is also working...
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59504461/8455396
Just read carefully and perform an action.

***html tag*** `hamburger button`

```
<a class="nav-link" data-widget="pushmenu" href="#" role="button"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></a>
```

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 /*
  check condition what value is stored in local storage if nothing then default 
  sidebar action would be performed you don't have to worry about this.
  In Admin lte version 3 sidebar-collapse added in body tag inspect you browser and check
 */
 if (window.localStorage.getItem('sidebar-toggle-collapsed') === 'false') {
        // if it is off sidebar-collapse close
        $("body").addClass("sidebar-collapse");
    } else {
        $("body").removeClass("sidebar-collapse");
 }

// Perform click event action

 $("[data-widget='pushmenu']").click(function() {
        var buttonClickedValue = '';
        if (window.localStorage.getItem('sidebar-toggle-collapsed') === 'false') {
            buttonClickedValue = 'true';
        } else {
            buttonClickedValue = 'false';
        }
       
        // store value in local storage
        window.localStorage.setItem('sidebar-toggle-collapsed', buttonClickedValue );
  });

});
</script>
```